# R shiny app: Pass URL parameters to global.R

Tags: r, shiny

I have a shiny app that consists of a global, ui and server R-script. I start the app using the webbrowser (e.g. `shinyapp.com/?usefulInformation`). I want to extract the `usefulInformation` part of the URL to be used in global.R. I know I can obtain URL information using `parseQueryString(session$clientData$url_search)`, but this only works in the server function. Since global.R is executed before server.R, is there a way to obtain the URL information before the server script is executed?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: As you code snipped implies the data you are trying to access is session dependent. The server function manages the sessions. Accordingly I don't see any way you can solve this. Maybe you could use a proxy server which is accessed before starting the app - but I guess it might be easier to rethink, whether you global code really needs to run globally.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! You've got a good point regarding whether to use global variables is wise in this case. This is done initially because global.R loads a large dataset I'm using throughout the rest of the app. I just want to select which dataset to load out of a list of many datasets. Thing is that I'm modifying an already existing app and for me it is not feasible rebuilding the entire app just for this.

Comment: You could use `reactiveFileReader` or `reactivePoll` and set `session = NULL` to create a cross-session reactive dataset (see the examples in `?reactiveFileReader`) from within the server function. Unfortunately you didn't provide any code, so I can't tell in which format your "large dataset" is present.